# Accidently deleted PATH environment variable - how do I get it back?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, environment-variables

I had to add the JDK path in the system variables which is under environment variables, but by mistake I deleted the default path which was present in the Path and pasted the JDK path.

So how do I get the default path back?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which OS you're on: MAC/Windows/Linux....

Under Linux it's simple, just close the terminal window you're in. The PATH environment variable is restored when a new tab is opened.

Probably similar in newer (2004+) MACs.

Windows... that's tricky because the more applications you have installed the more chance you have of other applications having added their information to the PATH variable and simply using a default-install one will not "fix" your issues.

One option, although unpleasant, would be to use "SYSTEM RESTORE" to go back to the most recent version of your backups and going from there.... as long as you haven't added much software since then the chances of you missing something else that you need are slim. You will have to reinstall windows updates, though.

**edit**: just saw the main thread is tagged Windows7. So the comment from the above user is probably helpful, but the answer I provided at the end is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The "Path" system variable is different depending on which applications you've installed.  However, as a starting point, the following is included with Windows itself.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

If you use PowerShell, add:

```
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

If you use Windows Live (including Windows Essentials 2012), add:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
```

Make sure to separate any additions with a semi-colon (`;`)!